# Use Dependency Injection with Reachability(internet checking) Class?

Tags: swift, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I'm Checking internet Connection several times in my app with the Reachability class,

and i want to use DI.

How may i do it?

Reachabilty class:

```
public class Reachability {
class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {
    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
    let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
    }
    var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
    if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
        return false
    }
    let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
    let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
    return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
}
```

Comment: since your function is a class function there is no need for DI, or you want to know how to change the function to make it suitable for DI?

Comment: exactly, second option plz, i looking for a way to build a request manager that will manage the times i need that specific class.

Answer (score 1):

Dependency Injection (DI) makes a little sense if you can't switch between dependency implementations, so we'll introduce a protocol for the dependency. With some changes to your class I see it with DI pattern as follows.

```
protocol Reachability {
    var connectedToNetwork: Bool { get }
}

class DefaultReachability: Reachability {

    var connectedToNetwork: Bool {
        // ...
    }

}

// Example of a dependend class
class Some {

    let reachability: Reachability

    init(reachability: Reachability) {
        self.reachability = reachability // Now it is dependency
    }

    func action() {
        if reachability.connectedToNetwork {
            // ...
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }

}
```